# Finding the proportion of candidates that passed both Math and English.

Tags: percentages

In an examination, $35$% of the candidates failed in Mathematics and $25$% in English. If $10$% failed in both Math and English then how many percent passed in both the subjects?

**ATTEMPT**
Let $x$ be total candidates. Then $\frac{35x}{100}$ failed in Math, $\frac{x}{4}$ failed in English, $\frac{x}{10}$ failed in both.

So now i look for candidates who failed in either Math or English which is the union of the above two.

Candidates who failed in either Math or English = Candidates who failed in Maths + Candidates who failed in English - Candidates who failed in both.

SO it becomes $7x/20 + x/4 - x/10$

Now percent of  candidates who passed in both are $1 - \{ 7x/20 + x/4 - x/10 \}$.

But i am kind of stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. Forget the fractions.

Comment: What is the problem then? You are doing it all-right..

Comment: @anshabhi how do i come up with answer which is 50 %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7/20 = 0.35$

$1/4 = 0.20$

$1/10 = 0.10$

now,  $1 - { 7/20 + 1/4 - 1/10 } = 0.5$

Thus, ($1 - 0.50)*100$  That is, **50% students passed.**

Comment: where is x      .........        ?

Comment: when you are talking about percentages, you don't have to take care of x.

Comment: can you show actual method with x

Comment: 1 - { 7x/20 + x/4 - x/10 } is actually  x - { 7x/20 + x/4 - x/10 }, since you can't subtract variable from integer. Simply, take x common from it and write  1 - { 7/20 + 1/4 - 1/10 }

Comment: Stop using x! The value of x is $1$ (!) because it is the PROPORTION/PERCENT of students, and that total is 1 (100%).

Answer (score 1):

Stop using *x*.

Let $P(M)$ be the percent of students who failed math.

Let $P(E)$ be the percent of students who failed English.

The percent of students who failed one or the other (or both) $ = P(M \lor E)$.
$$P(M \lor E) = P(M) + P(E) - P(M \land E)$$
$$P(M \lor E) = .35 + .25 - .10 = .50$$

The percent of students who PASSED both is the complement of $P(M \lor E)$.